# Stop python writing json file to one line

Tags: python, json

How can I force Python to stop writing my `.json` file to one line? I've tried changing the write command `with open('manifest.json', 'wb') as f:` to `with open('manifest.json', 'w') as f:` but it is still writing to one line.

#### Code

```
import json

with open('manifest.json', 'r') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
    json_data['server-version'] = "xxxx-x.x.x"

with open('manifest.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(json_data))

print('Successful.')
```

Comment: try in your python console: `help(json.dumps)` and `help(json.dump)`.

Comment: try using json.dumps(json_data, indent=4)

Comment: @Romaan, that actually works! thank you so much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pretty print JSON python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792848/pretty-print-json-python)

Comment: I looked at that question and i didn't understand it, that's why I posted my own question and for clarification. :)@Dawson

Comment: this is probably the wrong way to look at things: formatting JSON with whitespace is an additive operation. You are increasing the content, and adding undefined bias.  It is harder to process, harder to parse, and cannot be accumulated in a file linewise for easy parallelization.  You should think of formatting the JSON as a feature you might *add* for human readability that has a large usability downside; not as a default defined such that  un-formatted JSON is a "restriction" to some more complex state (it is not; **unformatted json with a newline suffix is a simplification**).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For pretty printing use indent parameter

```
print(json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
```